# Understanding Java util Date

Tags: java, date, java.util.date

Why does java.util.Date object show date & time with respect to a timezone when in actuality, java.util.Date represents an instant on the time-line, not a "date"?
The actual data stored within the object is a long count of milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00Z (midnight at the start of 1970 GMT/UTC).

Also in docs, A java.util.Date instance has no concept of time-zone.

If so is the case, why does this snippet print date specifying timezone.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date date = new Date();
        System.out.println(date);
    }
```

Output : Wed Mar 22 14:58:56 IST 2017

Why is it showing specific timezone in the output? I understand the SOP implements toString() internally. Does toString() effect the timezone?

Comment: All the ambiguity with `Date` is a good reason for using the new `java.time` classes, like [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)/[`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html).

Comment: The Javadocs for `java.util.Date#toString` are quite clear on this, and are arguably the obvious first place to look for answers to questions about `java.util.Date#toString`. There we find that indeed, as you surmised, `toString` is wired to use time zone information, when available.

Comment: To print a point on the time-line, you have to use some time zone. The designers decided for the local time zone instead of UTC.

Comment: Back in Java 1.0 when the `Date` class was designed and there were no plans to make a `Calendar` class let alone `LocalDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime` this probably seemed like a reasonable choice.

Comment: As commented by Ole V.V.… FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: Just wondering: is there a specific reason you didnt accept one of the answers here?

Answer (score 4):

Just follow the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString--), as it says:

> public String toString()
>
> Converts this Date object to a String of the form:
>
> dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy
>
> zzz is the time zone (and may reflect daylight saving time).

And when you dive into the source code, that this toString() implementation will at some point use [TimeZone.getDefault()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault())
( or to be precise: getDefaultRef()). In other words: the default implementation pulls in the "default" timezone of your JVM.

Comment: Edited to replace "system" with "JVM". The JVM maintains its own current default time zone which may differ from that of the host OS.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

Current moment in UTC.

```
Instant.now()    // Capture current moment in UTC.
    .toString()  // Generate String in standard ISO 8601 format.
```

> 2018-01-23T01:23:45.677340Z

Current moment in India time zone.

```
ZonedDateTime.now( 
    ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) 
).toString()    // Generate string in format wisely extended from ISO 8601 standard, adding the time zone name in square brackets.
```

> 2018-01-23T06:53:45.677340+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

> Why does java.util.Date object show date & time with respect to a timezone when in actuality, java.util.Date represents an instant on the time-line, not a "date"?

Because the `java.util.Date` and related classes (`Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`, and such) are poorly-designed. While a valiant effort at tackling the tricky subject of date-time handling, they fall short of the goal. They are riddled with poor design choices. You should avoid them, as they are now supplanted by the *java.time* classes, an *enormous* improvement.

Specifically to answer your question: The `toString` method of `Date` dynamically applies the JVM’s current default time zone while generating a String. So while the `Date` object itself represents a moment in UTC, the `toString` creates the false impression that it carries the displayed time zone.

Even worse, there *is* a time zone buried inside the `Date` object. That zone is used internally, yet is irrelevant to our discussion here. Confusing? Yes, yet another reason to avoid this class.

> A java.util.Date instance has no concept of time-zone.

Not true. A `Date` represents a specific moment, a point on the timeline, with a resolution of milliseconds, in UTC. As you mention, it is defined as a count of milliseconds since the first moment of 1970 in UTC.

## java.time

The *java.time* classes separate clearly the concepts of UTC, zoned, and unzoned values.

The [`java.time.Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).  This class replaces `java.util.Date`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture current moment in UTC.
```

Apply a time zone (`ZoneId` object) to an `Instant` and you get a `ZonedDateTime` object. That class replaces the `java.util.Calendar` class.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;  // Same simultaneous moment as `instant`, but different wall-clock time.
```

If a value has only an offset-from-UTC but not a full time zone, use the `OffsetDateTime` class.

For a date only, without time-of-day and without time zone, use the `LocalDate` class. This class replaces the `java.sql.Date` class. Ditto for `LocalTime` replacing `java.sql.Time`.

```
LocalDate xmasDate2018 = LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.DECEMBER , 25 ) ;
```

If the zone or offset are unknown or indeterminate, such as "Christmas starts at stroke of midnight on December 25, 2018", use the `LocalDateTime` class. This class does *not* represent an actual moment, a specific point on the timeline. This class lacks any concept of time zone or offset. So it can only represent potential moments along a range of about 26-27 hours.

```
LocalDateTime xmasEverywhere2018 = LocalDateTime.of( xmasDate2018 , LocalTime.MIN ) ;
```

Or…

```
LocalDateTime xmasEverywhere2018 = LocalDateTime.of( 2018 , Month.DECEMBER , 25 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

With a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) complying with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later, you may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. No need for strings or java.sql.* classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

It does have a concept of time zone, but it is always UTC.  When it prints the date therefore there is no problem converting it to the time zone of your computer.